# Disable/enable inner controls in a custom listview

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a two button an a EditText  in a custom listview, I have a couple buttons setted his cliclisteners to disable the two buttons and set read only the edittext that resides into the listview.
The first one button in the acctivity activate the controls in the listview an the other deactivate them
How I approach this I search in the web and dont find any solution

Comment: Create a class that extends ArrayAdapter and overide the getView() method and return your custom layout in which you will set your OnClickListeners and then set the adapter of your listview to that class

Comment: I Already do it the queestion is how activate or deactivate the inside control in the listview from the mainactivity

Comment: why can't you just create an appropriate method in your custom listview? Something like: `setControlsEnabled(boolean enabled)` ? Inside this method you activate or deactivate your controls. And then you can call this method from your activity where custom listview is defined